# Autofac open generics: factory IIndex based on <U>

Tags: c#, generics, autofac

New to Autofac here.

I want to end up using a factory which picks up an instance based on an enumeration key.

Example:

```
public enum TransactionType
{
    one,
    two,
    three
}

public interface IResponse
{
    TransactionType type { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseOne : IResponse
{
    public TransactionType type { get; set; } = TransactionType.one;
}

public class ResponseTwo : IResponse
{
    public TransactionType type { get; set; } = TransactionType.two;
}

public class ResponseThree : IResponse
{
    public TransactionType type { get; set; } = TransactionType.three;
}

public interface IRequest { }

public interface IClient<U>
    where U : IResponse
{
    void DoWork<T>(T Request)
        where T : class, IRequest, new();
}

public class Client<U> : IClient<U>
    where U : class, IResponse, new()
{
    U Response;

    public void DoWork<T>(T Request)
        where T : class, IRequest, new()
    {
        Response = default(U);
    }
}
```

What I want Autofac to do is feed a factory with the necessary IIndex so that I can pick the correct client based on <U>. The factory is as follows:

```
public class ClientFactory
{
    readonly IIndex<TransactionType, IClient<IResponse>> Clients;

    public ClientFactory(IIndex<TransactionType, IClient<IResponse>> Clients)
    {
        this.Clients = Clients;
    }

    public IClient<IResponse> PickClient(TransactionType type) => Clients[type];
}
```

I have come this far with the builder:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType<Client<ResponseOne>>()
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .Keyed<IClient<IResponse>>(TransactionType.one);

builder.RegisterType<Client<ResponseTwo>>()
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .Keyed<IClient<IResponse>>(TransactionType.two);

builder.RegisterType<Client<ResponseThree>>()
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .Keyed<IClient<IResponse>>(TransactionType.three);
```

1) I have no clue about how to do this in a more elegant way, if there is any. Namely: dear Autofac, please generate an IIndex containing an IClient for every IResponse in the assembly, keyed by its type.

2) It seems more straightforward for me to use Container.Resolve than going through the fuss of using a factory (the Autofac open generics documentation chapter says so). Isn't this a service location (= an anti-pattern)?

Thank you.

Comment: Although your code allows it, I assume the responses will not change their transactiontype?

Comment: Yes, your assumption is correct.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?  I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I'm afraid not. I'm stuck with what I mentioned in the builder section. It works, and I have no more time to give to it. Still a more elegant solution is to be found.